# Dart - declare function as variable

Tags: function, variables, dart, function-declaration

In Dart - as in many other languages - there is more than one way to declare a function. The question is, are there any differences aka "when should I use which"?

```
void foo(int i) {
  print('i = $i');
}

void main() {
  void Function(int) bar = (int j) {
    print('j = $j');
  };

  foo(1);
  bar(2);
}
```

Is there any difference in the declaration of `foo` or `bar` other than the fact that `bar` can be overwritten?

Comment: There are also a difference in scope. Your `bar` function are inside your `main` method scope and can therefore access variables defined in `main` (if you e.g. define a variable before your `bar` variable).

Comment: [Effective Dart recommends declaring functions when possible](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#do-use-a-function-declaration-to-bind-a-function-to-a-name).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functions can be introduced by

- function declarations
- method decla-rations
- getter declarations
- setter declarations
- constructor declarations
- function literals

In terms of [Dart specification](https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.2.pdf) there is 2 differences between function literals (aka anonymous function) and other declarations

1. it has no name - anonymous
2. we can't declare a return type (which only obtained by means of type inference)

If you prefer to keep type safety, you will have to write long declaration.

Consider this example:

```
String foo(int i, {bool b}) => '$b $i'; // return type declared

final bar = (int i, {bool b}) => '$b $i'; // return type could not be infered

final String Function(int i, {bool b}) bar = (i, {b}) => '$b $i'; // return type infered
```

From my perspective

1. `bar` isn't as readable as `foo` declaration
2. Let functions literals do their anonymous job =)

PS If I missed anything - please edit my answer or reach me in comments